# Maintaining Clip Layer Attributes When Using Clip Tool in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, clip, spatial-analysis

I am looking to clip master map polygons to land owner boundaries. However, the normal clip tool does not allow me to identify which land owner the master map parcel belongs to once it has been clipped. The master map polygons only maintain their own attributes. I have tried a spatial join using 'completely within' operation, but this misses out some polygons.

The 'intersect' operation picks up several of the clipping boundaries where there are two adjacent to each other.

Is there another way to identify which landowner polygon each mastermap poly belongs to?

Comment: You could use the "Union" tool for this.  After performing the Union, you would have to effectively 'clip' the result by deleting all the features that have a NULL value for the owner FID field.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  When asking questions about ArcGIS Desktop please always mention whether you are using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application (not both) within your question body.